# Wildcard in implicit rule's prerequisites

Tags: makefile

```
BUILT_DIR = /tmp/obj 
SRC = /source/dir  

/tmp/obj/%/builtin.o : $(SRC)/%/*.c
      gcc $^ -o $@
```

But you know :

> In order for the pattern rule to apply, its target pattern must match the file name under consideration and all of its prerequisites (after pattern substitution) must name files that exist or can be made.

If i execute `make /tmp/obj/hfa/builtin.o`,make will complain :

`make: *** No rule to make target`/tmp/obj/hfa/builtin.o'.  Stop.`

How can i modify the Makefile to satisfy my requirement？

Comment: Make will only complain in this case because there are no `/source/dir/hfa/*.c` files.  Because no `.c` files exist, there is no target pattern match and so the implicit rule is not matched.  What is your requirement?

Comment: I have `hfa.c` in `/source/dir/hfa/`

Comment: What version of Make are you using? (Try `make -v` if you do not know.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Secondary Expansion

```
BUILT_DIR = /tmp/obj 
SRC = /source/dir  
.SECONDEXPANSION:
/tmp/obj/%/builtin.o : $$(wildcard $(SRC)/%/*.c)
      gcc $^ -o $@
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you see indicates that there are no .c files which match the pattern `$(SRC)/hfa/*.c` since the `%` translates into `hfa`. So make cannot use the rule you've defined.

Make then starts to use the implicit rules for building and it would not match either.

Finally make gives up.

I just confirmed that the same Makefile and I get the same error only when there are no `*.c` files in the `$(SRC)/hfa` directory.

Otherwise, I see the gcc command getting executed.

And from your question, it is not quite clear what your requirement is.

Comment: `*.c` is a wildcard.  I have `hfa.c` in `$(SRC)/hfa`. Only when `/tmp/obj/%/builtin.o : $(SRC)/%/hfa.c` make will success.

Comment: @jianxisun - Are you asking why is it that, make succeeds only when giving the make target as `/tmp/obj/hfa/builtin.o` ? To answer that, yes because only under that condition, your rule would match.

Comment: Why requirements can not have a wildcard. If write requirement like `$(SRC)/%/*c`,make will match nothing.I have checked `$(SRC)/%/hfa.c` which will match the rule.

Answer (score 0):

The rule configuration that worked for me:

```
bar-%-foo:
  @touch $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
foo-%-bar: bar-$$*-foo
  @echo "@: $@"
  @echo "<: $<"
  @touch $@

foo-bar: foo-biz-bar foo-baz-bar
.PHONY: foo-bar
```

And demo:

```
$:make foo-bar
@: foo-biz-bar
<: bar-biz-foo
@: foo-baz-bar
<: bar-baz-foo
rm bar-biz-foo bar-baz-foo

$:ls | grep foo
foo-baz-bar
foo-biz-bar
```